# Connect to mongo during docker build (Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27010)

Tags: mongodb, docker

I'm trying to build a customer Dockerfile which forks 3 instances of MongoDB on different ports. In the end I'm trying to build a replicaset out of those 3 and use it in my integration tests. As I am using transactions, I need it to be a replicaset. Anyway, I started building it on ubundu images and though I've had some problems, I am finally getting somewhere. All the three nodes are starting up at least. But as a final step of this build I need to feed one of those three instances a few commands. But I can't connect to my mongo in the very same Docker script. What am I doing wrong? My Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

ADD cluster-conf.js /cluster-conf.js

RUN apt-get update -y        # Fetches the list of available updates
RUN apt-get upgrade -y       # Installs some updates; does not remove packages
RUN apt-get full-upgrade -y  # Installs updates; may also remove some packages, if needed
RUN apt-get autoremove -y

RUN apt-get install wget -y
RUN apt-get install gnupg -y

RUN ulimit -n 64000

RUN rm -rf /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb*.list

RUN wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.4.asc | apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.4 multiverse" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list
RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y mongodb-org-server; exit 0
RUN apt-get install -y mongodb-org; exit 0

RUN mkdir -p ~/mongodata/rs0-0 ~/mongodata/rs0-1 ~/mongodata/rs0-2
RUN mkdir -p ~/mongologs/rs0-0 ~/mongologs/rs0-1 ~/mongologs/rs0-2

RUN sleep 2

RUN mongod --port 27010 --bind_ip_all --dbpath ~/mongodata/rs0-0 --replSet rs0 --oplogSize 128 --logpath ~/mongologs/rs0-0/server.log --fork; exit 0
RUN mongod --port 27011 --bind_ip_all --dbpath ~/mongodata/rs0-1 --replSet rs0 --oplogSize 128 --logpath ~/mongologs/rs0-1/server.log --fork; exit 0
RUN mongod --port 27012 --bind_ip_all --dbpath ~/mongodata/rs0-2 --replSet rs0 --oplogSize 128 --logpath ~/mongologs/rs0-2/server.log --fork; exit 0

RUN sleep 3
RUN cat ~/mongologs/rs0-0/server.log
RUN sleep 3
RUN mongo --port 27010 #</cluster-conf.js Will uncomment this if I get the connection working
```

When running `docker build .` last lines of logs are:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-21T18:17:35.763+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":21531,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Initialized the rollback ID","attr":{"rbid":1}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-21T18:17:35.763+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":21313,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Did not find local replica set configuration document at startup","attr":{"error":{"code":47,"codeName":"NoMatchingDocument","errmsg":"Did not find replica set configuration document in local.system.replset"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-21T18:17:35.765+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":40440,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Starting the TopologyVersionObserver"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-21T18:17:35.765+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20712,   "ctx":"LogicalSessionCacheReap","msg":"Sessions collection is not set up; waiting until next sessions reap interval","attr":{"error":"NamespaceNotFound: config.system.sessions does not exist"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-21T18:17:35.765+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":40445,   "ctx":"TopologyVersionObserver","msg":"Started TopologyVersionObserver"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-21T18:17:35.765+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20714,   "ctx":"LogicalSessionCacheRefresh","msg":"Failed to refresh session cache, will try again at the next refresh interval","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Replication has not yet been configured"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-21T18:17:35.766+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23015,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Listening on","attr":{"address":"/tmp/mongodb-27010.sock"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-21T18:17:35.766+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23015,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Listening on","attr":{"address":"0.0.0.0"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-21T18:17:35.766+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23016,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Waiting for connections","attr":{"port":27010,"ssl":"off"}}
Removing intermediate container 3f6746aa40b2
 ---> 3eef7f166633
Step 24/25 : RUN sleep 3
 ---> Running in 387128b5cc40
Removing intermediate container 387128b5cc40
 ---> 8574e30fae90
Step 25/25 : RUN mongo --port 27010
 ---> Running in 351734d713a7
MongoDB shell version v4.4.0
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27010/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27010, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27010 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:362:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1
The command '/bin/sh -c mongo --port 27010' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

So the logs say it is waiting for connections, but I can't actually connect. Whats up with that?

Comment: Besides the fact that I do not really think what you are trying is a good practice, what your are doing wrong is that each `RUN` step takes place in its own container that gets cleaned-up at the end. So by the time you try to connect, the container used to make the layer where you start mongo is long gone and mongo is not running in the new container for the next layer. If you really want to do that, you need to start mongo and connect to it in the same `RUN` step by seperating your commands with `;` or `&&`, the latest being the most common in Dockerfiles for error reporting reasons.

Comment: Thank you, this was it. I did not know that each RUN line will run in its own container but now that I think of it, it makes sense. By the way, I am well aware that what I am doing is an awful practice in 99% of the cases, but as I am just trying to run some integration tests in my spring app and start this ephermal docker container for some repository tests, I think it's totally ok. Anyway, it works perfectly for what I need and I dont intend to use it in production or anywhere.